# Drop a row if it contains a certain value in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have this text file:

```
LEU,LEID,PPP,YYY,LEO
'1','2','3','4','5'
'2','1','2','3','4'
'2','AA','','',''
```

I want to delete the rows where for LEID='1'

```
import pandas as pd
import os

originalFile=os.path.abspath("D:\\python\\test\\OriginalFile.csv")

df = pd.read_csv(originalFile)

df = df[(df['LEID'] !='1')]

df.to_csv('D:\\python\\test\\CorrectedFile.csv')

print (df)
```

Why the row with LEID='1' is not delted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have it, the quote characters are still included in your dataframe. It probably looks like:

```
>>> df
   LEU  LEID  PPP  YYY  LEO
0  '1'   '2'  '3'  '4'  '5'
1  '2'   '1'  '2'  '3'  '4'
2  '2'  'AA'   ''   ''   ''
```

So you would actually need to include those quotes in your filter. You can do this like:

```
df[df['LEID'] != "'1'"]
# or:
df[df['LEID'] !='\'1\'']

   LEU  LEID  PPP  YYY  LEO
0  '1'   '2'  '3'  '4'  '5'
2  '2'  'AA'   ''   ''   ''
```

An alternative would be to remove your single quotes when you read the csv:

```
df = pd.read_csv(originalFile, sep=',', quotechar="'")
```

And you will get this dataframe:

```
>>> df
   LEU LEID  PPP  YYY  LEO
0    1    2  3.0  4.0  5.0
1    2    1  2.0  3.0  4.0
2    2   AA  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Which you can filter like you were trying:

```
df[df['LEID' ]!= '1']

   LEU LEID  PPP  YYY  LEO
0    1    2  3.0  4.0  5.0
2    2   AA  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. It is strange as I tried both with removing the quotes before import and for some reason I still did not managed.

Answer (score 0):

`df[(df['LEID'] !='1')]` selects on columns. You need `df.loc[df['LEID'] !='1']`

Comment: Both the methods you provided would work equivalently for most applications in a normal case, but I don't think that's where OP's problem is coming from. I believe it has to do with the quote characters